# mod_rewrite RewriteRule and html links

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm creating a new website and it has some php in it. The site basically would work like this, i have /index.php?page=category_page. The the category would be the category and the page would be the sort-of sub category / actual page. The rewritten rule would look like this: /category/page.

I've got this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But i dont know how to separate the category and the page, any help?
The second thing is, in my index.php (for instance) i have some css from an external file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css"/>
```

This doesn't work with the rewrite rule, because it tries to load /category/page/style/style.css which doesn't exist / doesn't rewrite. How do i make it work? I know a simple fix would be to put /style/style.css and that would load from the root of the website, but i'm currently running the website from a sub directory e.g. example.com/new/index.php so that isn't an option. Any help with this?

Comment: For the second thing add a trailing slash to your path: `/style/style.css`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

You could define multiple parameters in your regex, e.g. category & page (see below).

With such a broad rewrite rule, you would want to add a condition not to rewrite for stylesheets, images, and other assets, though.

I also modified your pattern to only match letters, digits, hyphens, and underscores, which would prevent the use of non-standard characters in your category or page names.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|png|gif|jpg)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w\d\-]+)/([\w\d\-]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

**Problem 2:**

You're using a relative url in your href, which is appending the stylesheet's location to the current location defined in your browser (/category/page/).

Even though the server-side is rewriting that URL, the browser is unaware of the rewrite.

If you use an absolute URL instead, your browser will define the URL relative to the BASE url (/).

Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/style.css"/>
```

Comment: Is `([^/]*)` correct in this case? Shouldn't there be at least one characater before/after slash? `*` is `0 or more`

Comment: Pay attention, not every shared hoster does support the character groups \w and \d. So if the rewrite rule does not work try it with the native group [A-Za-z0-9]

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly! Also, this is on my personal server so i didnt have that problem TiMESPLiNTER

Answer (score 1):

Use this RewriteRule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/$ index.php?page=$1_$2 [L]
```